# Reading RAM and Disk utilization for VM's in Hyper-V using WMI Classes

Tags: c#, memory-management, wmi, ram, hyper-v

I am new to WMI Classes, I want to read CPU, RAM and Disk Utilization for different Virtual machines on Hyper-V using WMI Classes in C# code.

**CPU Utilization:** Able to get it by using properties ProcessorLoad and ProcessorLoadHistory

```
     ManagementBaseObject outParams = virtualSystemService.InvokeMethod("GetSummaryInformation", inParams, null);

     ManagementBaseObject[] summaryInformationArray = (ManagementBaseObject[])outParams["SummaryInformation"];
```

**RAM Utilization:** Not able to get exact value of current RAM utilization for dynamic and static allocation.
VirtualQuantity and Reservation  proprty of 'Msvm_MemorySettingData' class gives the startup RAM value in case of dynamic RAM and Minimum value of RAM allocated in case of static RAM.

**HardDisk Utilization**: Not able to get Harddisk utilization of each virtual machine.

My code is:

```
public static ManagementObject GetTargetComputer(string vmElementName, ManagementScope scope)
    {
        string query = string.Format("select * from Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName = '{0}'", vmElementName);

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(query));

        ManagementObjectCollection computers = searcher.Get();

        ManagementObject computer = null;

        foreach (ManagementObject instance in computers)
        {
            computer = instance;
            break;
        }
        return computer;
    }

void GetSummaryInformation(ManagementObject virtualSystemSettings, UInt32[] requestedInformation, ManagementObject virtualSystemService)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = virtualSystemService.GetMethodParameters("GetSummaryInformation");
        string[] settingPaths = new string[1];
        settingPaths[0] = virtualSystemSettings.Path.Path;
        inParams["SettingData"] = settingPaths;
        inParams["RequestedInformation"] = requestedInformation;
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = virtualSystemService.InvokeMethod("GetSummaryInformation", inParams, null);

        UInt32 v = (UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"];

        if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == 0)
        {
            ManagementBaseObject[] summaryInformationArray = (ManagementBaseObject[])outParams["SummaryInformation"];

            foreach (ManagementBaseObject summaryInformation in summaryInformationArray)
            {

                foreach (UInt32 requested in requestedInformation)
                {
                    string Name = summaryInformation["Name"].ToString();
                    switch (requested)//103, 106, 109, 104, 3, 4, 101, 105
                    {

                        case 103:
                            string MemoryUsage = summaryInformation["MemoryUsage"].ToString();
                            break;
                        case 112:
                            Int32 MemoryAvailable = (Int32)summaryInformation["MemoryAvailable"];
                            break;
                        case 113:
                            Int32 AvailableMemoryBuffer = (Int32)summaryInformation["AvailableMemoryBuffer"];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve virtual system summary information");
        }

        inParams.Dispose();
        outParams.Dispose();
    }


ManagementObject virtualSystem = GetTargetComputer(vm["ElementName"].ToString(), Scope);

            ManagementObjectCollection virtualSystemSettings = virtualSystem.GetRelated
           (
               "Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData",
               "Msvm_SettingsDefineState",
               null,
               null,
               "SettingData",
               "ManagedElement",
               false,
               null
           );
            ManagementObject virtualSystemSetting = null;               
            foreach (ManagementObject instance in virtualSystemSettings)
            {
                virtualSystemSetting = instance;

                foreach (ManagementObject memorySettingData in virtualSystemSetting.GetRelated("Msvm_MemorySettingData"))
                {
                    string HeartBeat = (string)memorySettingData["Heartbeat"];
                    string MemoryUsage = (string)memorySettingData["MemoryUsage"];
                    string VirtualQuantity = (string)memorySettingData["VirtualQuantity"];
                    string Limit = (string)memorySettingData["Limit"];
                }


            }
            UInt32[] requestedInfo = { 103, 112, 113 };
            GetSummaryInformation(virtualSystemSetting, requestedInfo, virtualSystemService);
```

Is it possible to get the current RAM utilization and Harddisk utilization of each individual virtual machine in Hyper-V using WMI classes ?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Is there any solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

To find out RAM utilization, you may want to check out the following 'Hyper-V dynamic memory' example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-dynamic-memory-9b0b1d05

It may also provide you with insight on how to obtain the other information you are looking for.